# Is there a better way to work with Flex Builder and the AMF Gateway?

Tags: apache-flex, jboss, amf, gateway

I'm using Flex Builder 3 to connect to a bunch of back-end code via the AMF gateway.  Another developer packaged up all the AMF Gateway code into a war file.  Here's my development process:

- Deploy most recent AMF-gateway.war file into local jboss server
- War file gets unpacked into [jboss]/server/tmp/deploy/tmp23241AMF-gateway-exp.war/
- Run Flex Builder.  Point application project at AMF Gateway tmp folder in 3 places (Flex server root folder, Flex build output folder, Flex compiler 'additional arguments' (pointing to location of services-config.xml).

This setup means that whenever you start a debug session in Flex Builder, it dumps working versions of the files into the AMF-gateway folder on the jboss server (which is aliased as /AMF-gateway).  The thing is, every time I restart jboss or deploy an updated AMF-gateway.war file, it gets unpacked into a new temp folder with a new name, and I need to change all the references in the Flex project.  This happens several times a day, and it's annoying.  Can I streamline this configuration? I tried using an alias to that folder -- figuring I could script the change -- but Flex Builder didn't seem to like it.

Comment: What version of JBoss are you using?  It'll help to know because I'm not sure if they changed the paths in v5.

Comment: 4.2.3; I think a library we're using isn't yet compatible with 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can create a directory in JBoss that the server will treat as an exploded war file. I don't have a copy of JBoss handy to check, but I remember creating a directory such as "context-name.war" and being able to develop against that. So instead of copying your packaged .war file to the deploy directory, you could unzip it directly to that directory. If I remember correctly JBoss will monitor the web.xml file for changes and if it's overwritten it will redeploy the context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an XML approach: (i.e. SOAP/WSDL/REST), try using AMF to port to a different gateway such as C# to the database directly.

http://specialmoves.com/labs/code/flash-data-transfer-using-fluorinefx

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.